# S3 policy when using root access key and secret key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

So, I recently created a new AWS account to use S3 storage. I currently have only my root user account. I am using java aws-sdk to upload files. S3Client object is setup using my root account secret key and access key. Also, simply using aws-sdk inbuilt putObject() method to upload. Nothing fancy here.

Now, I tried attaching policy to my bucket to restrict upload and download feature on the bucket. Firstly, I had given all S3object permissions to my bucket and could upload successfully through the code. Then I tried to attach only getObject, putObject, getObjectAcl, putObjectAcl in my policy, and could again upload successfully.

After this, I removed putObject and putObjectAcl, only had getObject permissions but surprisingly could still upload files using my code. I believe removing upload permissions would give me 403 Access Denied. Is it because I am using my root user access key and secret key, which gives some extra rights? Or is there something fundamental that I'm missing here?

My Policy without upload permission:

```
{
  "Id": "PolicyXXXXXXX",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "StmtXXXXXX",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:root"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The root user can do anything, unrestricted by policies. Are you using the root user, or an IAM User when doing these experiments?

Comment: I am using the root user for these operations. So I believe that's the reason here.

Comment: If you are the only person using the AWS account, then using root credentials is fine. But, as soon as you have multiple users, it is best to avoid using the root account. Instead, create yourself an IAM User with Admin permissions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The user whose access key and secret key you are using, should have got the putObject permissions.

If resource-based policies and identity-based policies both apply to a request, then AWS checks all the policies for at least one `Allow`. Please refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-basics)
for policy evaluation logic.

If an action is allowed by an identity-based policy, a resource-based policy, or both, then AWS allows the action.

Comment: So since I'm using the root user keys for these operations, I believe root user has unrestricted permissions and hence I'm able to upload?

Comment: Yes, you got it. Also, avoid using root user credentials. Instead create a user with admin rights and use admin user's credentials.